# How do I get one data.frame to take on the column types as another in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, casting

Please ignore the prints and lack of all cases in the following:

```
normalize_type <- function(df1,df2) {
  for (vn in names(df1)) {
    if (vn %in% colnames(df1) & vn %in% colnames(df2)) { 
      if (typeof(df2[[vn]]) != typeof(df1[[vn]])) { 
        if (typeof(df2[[vn]]) %in% c('double','numeric')) {
          df1[[vn]] <- as.numeric(df1[[vn]])
          print(paste(vn, "changed to numeric/double"))
        } else if (typeof(df2[[vn]]) == 'integer') {
          df1[[vn]] <- as.integer(df1[[vn]])
          print(paste(vn, "changed to integer"))
        } else if (typeof(df2[[vn]]) == 'factor') {
          df1[[vn]] <- as.factor(df1[[vn]])
          print(paste(vn, "changed to factor"))
        }
       } else {
         print(paste(vn, ": ", typeof(df1[[vn]]), "matched", typeof(df2[[vn]])))
       }
     } else {
       print(paste(vn, "is not in both data frames"))
     }
   }
   df1
 }
```

I am in the midst of writing some machine learning models for an R course assignment, wherein I am given training and testing data.  What I found, however, was that the test data had significantly less data than the training set, and as a result many of the columns were coerced, on read, into different data types... against which I could not run prediction algorithms as a result.  So I wrote the above to try to coerce it into the same times, based on the assumption that I shouldn't be able to KNOW what is in the test data and cull unnecessary columns from the training data, after all.

My simple question is... is there a way to butcher this less?  Some R one-liner that does the same general thing?  I tried typeof(tst$x) <- typeof(trn$x) to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Without more context your code is unintelligible.

Comment: try `mt <- \`[<-.data.frame\`(mtcars, 1:32, 1:11, lapply(mtcars, as.character));
mtcars[] <- lapply(seq_along(mtcars), function(x) \`class<-\`(mtcars[, x], class(mt[, x])))`